# I am developing a site on 2 machines. One at home (no internet) and my VPS How can I update my server code to sync with my netbook code?

Tags: git, push

The issue is that I can not 'git push' changes from my netbook, to my online server, however, I can run 'git pull' on my netbook, and get added / modified files from the work I do on the server. I split my development time between the two machines equally, and I want a better way to keep the code in sync than creating tarballs.

I am a complete git newbie, so I don't know if this is even possible.  I chose git because I heard it was easy, and I do not have to worry about setting up an svn server.

Is git push even the right command???  So confused!

Also, I can not do a git pull and get the changes from my netbook onto my server.  I can not do this because when I am online, I am in a public place, and my vps can not access my netbook.

Cheers!

Comment: A quick rule of thumb is to never push into a repository that has a work tree attached to it, until you know what you are doing. (via http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/01/push-to-only-bare-repositories.html)

Comment: Your netbook can pull, which implies it has network access at least some time. Why can't you push?

Comment: When I do a push, it asks for my ssh password (i am using git over ssh), and then it does some hocus pocus.  After I do the push, I run a 'git status' on the server, and It tells me that the files that I added on my netbook are to be deleted... that cant be, because they need to be added!

Comment: What's a "netbook coed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing git push from whichever machine that you've just finished coding on, do a git pull from the other.

Comment: I am behind the library firewall.  There is no way to access my netbook from my vps.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: When you get push to a git repository, the VPS can then pull from it. You don't need the VPS to get to your netbook, just to the repository wherever it is (github, your own server, wherever else).

Comment: Thanks!  What you said was correct. I was not aware of some key concepts, and when I became aware, your advice worked.